# List array values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array like this

```
var cons=Array();
cons[random_text]=random_number;
cons[random_text]=random_number;
...
```

I want to list all values in cons variable.How can I do this in one loop ?

Comment: as I see here there is no array, it is kinda key value pair or a hashmap which in js is just a js object not an array. `random_text` should be `random_number` if you want to have an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no associative arrays in javascript, the index can be only numbers.
What you're creating is an object with key/value pairs, unless `random_text` for some reason actually is an integer, which would seem strange.

```
var cons = {}; // object, not array
cons[random_text] = random_number;
cons[random_text] = random_number;

// iterate

for (var key in cons) {
    var value = cons[key];

    console.log(key + ' : ' + value);
}
```

to get an array of the keys in modern browsers, there's also

```
var key_arr = Object.keys(cons);
```